# Triple question mark ("???") operator in swift?

Tags: ios, swift

Recently I gave an interview and I was asked about triple question mark `???` operator in swift. I didn't know about it so I googled it and can't find anything related. Is there any `???` operator in swift?

Comment: It's pretty easy to figure out yourself: Open [Basic Operators](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/BasicOperators.html) and [Advanced Operators](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/AdvancedOperators.html) in the Language Guide and search for `???`

Comment: @vadian I'm not familiar with `???` either, and don't see it on either of those pages. Are you saying it's in the docs somewhere (or that it even exists in stdlib)?

Comment: @RobNapier I just want to say, if it's not in the docs then it doesn't exist. ;-)

Comment: @vadian Generally true that it should be *somewhere* in the docs, but those pages don't cover all the operators. `~=` is buried down in the Language Reference (I don't think it's in the Guide at all). And the Compound Assignment operators aren't actually enumerated (which always burns folks when they find out >>= is already defined). IMO knowing that an operator doesn't exist is pretty hard without asking the compiler. I believe it's a good question and very hard to determine on your own (though a weird interview question).

Comment: @vadian I wish you had said that you meant that it doesn't exist if it's not found it the document right at the beginning.  I thought I was ignorant.

Answer (score 2):

There is no `???` operator in Swift (although there is `??`, the nil-coalescing operator). That said, Swift allows you to define your own operators, so it's possible that that's what your interviewers were expecting to hear about.